# How to run a keyboard command in a Bash script on Windows

Tags: windows, bash

I am trying to open up two windows of Alacritty with bash then resize them to take half the screen each.
I thought it may be possible to use windowskey + side arrows, but I'm not too sure how to run a keyboard command and how to apply it to a program.

Here is what I have so far:

```
start alacritty
```

What I'd like to do:

```
start alacritty WINDOWSKEY LEFT ARROW # left side
start alacritty WINDOWSKEY RIGHT ARROW # right side
```

Comment: Maybe something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)?  I don't know how well it adapts to bash, in particular since you did not specify which bash you are using (Cygwin, WSL, Git Bash....). I think this question is better asked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/), since the main problem is to find the right tool to script keystrokes. Therefore, I vote to close the question.

Comment: I posted it over on superuser, I'd close this question but I'm not too sure how.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't enough reputation yet to close questions, even your own. I think you have to wait until at least 3 moderators reap it.